# Ajax loaded table inside Twitter Bootstrap Accordion Collapse

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I am trying to load content for Twitter collapse via ajax, the content is in the form of twitter bootstrap tabs that contain html tables in them, this works up for the first tab and first collapsible menu, I am wondering what is the best way to load tabs inside Twitter bootstrap collapse via ajax? Here is a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/H36fG/

Code for the collapse layout
`
    
         Maize

```
    </div>
    <div id="Maize" class="accordion-body collapse">
        <div class="accordion-inner"></div> <a href="http://dev.ratin.net/core/index.php/site/product/Maize"
        class="btn btn-link">See More</a>   
    </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading"> <a class="accordion-toggle" id="2" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
        href="#Sorghum">
            Sorghum             </a>

    </div>
    <div id="Sorghum" class="accordion-body collapse">
        <div class="accordion-inner"></div> <a href="http://dev.ratin.net/core/index.php/site/product/Sorghum"
        class="btn btn-link">See More</a>   
    </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading"> <a class="accordion-toggle" id="3" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
        href="#Wheat">
            Wheat               </a>

    </div>
    <div id="Wheat" class="accordion-body collapse">
        <div class="accordion-inner"></div> <a href="http://dev.ratin.net/core/index.php/site/product/Wheat"
        class="btn btn-link">See More</a>   
    </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading"> <a class="accordion-toggle" id="4" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
        href="#Rice">
            Rice                </a>

    </div>
    <div id="Rice" class="accordion-body collapse">
        <div class="accordion-inner"></div> <a href="http://dev.ratin.net/core/index.php/site/product/Rice"
        class="btn btn-link">See More</a>   
    </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading"> <a class="accordion-toggle" id="5" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
        href="#Millet">
            Millet              </a>

    </div>
    <div id="Millet" class="accordion-body collapse">
        <div class="accordion-inner"></div> <a href="http://dev.ratin.net/core/index.php/site/product/Millet"
        class="btn btn-link">See More</a>   
    </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading"> <a class="accordion-toggle" id="6" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
        href="#Beans">
            Beans               </a>

    </div>
    <div id="Beans" class="accordion-body collapse">
        <div class="accordion-inner"></div> <a href="http://dev.ratin.net/core/index.php/site/product/Beans"
        class="btn btn-link">See More</a>   
    </div>
</div>
```

'

The loaded html table with tabs is:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="product-table">


<li><a href="#1" data-toggle="tab">Grade 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#2" data-toggle="tab">Grade 2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#3" data-toggle="tab">Grade 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="1">
      <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped volumes">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Warehouse</th>
            <th>Grain Volume</th>
            <th>Trade Volume</th>
            <th>Direction</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>NFRA MPANDA RUKWA</td>
            <td>487</td>
            <td>487.00</td>
            <td>IN</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>COTCORI Cooperative</td>
            <td>113</td>
            <td>113.00</td>
            <td>IN</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>ENAS GBC KIREHE</td>
            <td>131</td>
            <td>131.00</td>
            <td>IN</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Government Procurement and Supply Agent</td>
            <td>453</td>
            <td>453.00</td>
            <td>IN</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Nairobi(test)</td>
            <td>261</td>
            <td>250.00</td>
            <td>IN</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="2">
      <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped volumes">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Warehouse</th>
            <th>Grain Volume</th>
            <th>Trade Volume</th>
            <th>Direction</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>National Food Reserve Agency_Manyoni</td>
            <td>172</td>
            <td>172.00</td>
            <td>IN</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sodea GBC</td>
            <td>471</td>
            <td>20.00</td>
            <td>OUT</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Kivu Maize Factory</td>
            <td>389</td>
            <td>389.00</td>
            <td>IN</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mombasa Bulk Grain Handlers</td>
            <td>200</td>
            <td>200.00</td>
            <td>IN</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Zwii Enterprises-Muloza</td>
            <td>-47</td>
            <td>47.00</td>
            <td>OUT</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="3">
      <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped volumes">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Warehouse</th>
            <th>Grain Volume</th>
            <th>Trade Volume</th>
            <th>Direction</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>COTCORI Cooperative</td>
            <td>93</td>
            <td>93.00</td>
            <td>IN</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>SOSOMA GBC KICUKIRO</td>
            <td>-23</td>
            <td>23.00</td>
            <td>OUT</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Shabiby_Indivisual</td>
            <td>270</td>
            <td>270.00</td>
            <td>IN</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Silayo_Union Service Stores</td>
            <td>-38</td>
            <td>38.00</td>
            <td>OUT</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>SGR/NFRA VWAWA</td>
            <td>-39</td>
            <td>39.00</td>
            <td>OUT</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using Twitter Bootstrap 2.2 and Jquery 1.8.3, I am open to suggestions on how best I can present such data

Comment: I would keep as you are (loading on click) but put a loading gif in there to smoothen out the user experience. E.g. you click, the loading gif appears, once the ajax call returns you hide the gif and display the data.

Answer (score 0):

I would first make sure to only load the content once for each accord and then use the Ajax callback to apply the tabs settings and such.

Also, for your tab naming convention(I see you're using `<div id="1">` ), I would recommend not using numbers for the ID as I've seen this cause issues with JS/JQ, so maybe go with #tabs-one, #tabs-two, etc.

Here's a quick example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
        $('.accordion-toggle').on('click', function () {

            var parentRef     = $(this).attr('href'),
                $innerContent = $(parentRef).find('.accordion-inner');            

            //only load group once
            if($innerContent.text() ===''){
                $innerContent.load('http://fiddle.jshell.net/NPpHm/show/', function(){

                    var $this      = $(this),
                        $innerTabs = $this.find('.nav-tabs');

                    console.log($innerTabs);

                     var tabOpts = {
                            active: 0,                            
                            cookie: {expires: 3},
                            show:  onTabShow,            
                            fillSpace: false,
                            autoHeight: true,
                            collapsible: false
                        };


                    $innerTabs.tabs(tabOpts).fadeIn(700);   


                });
            }

    });
});
```